# Complexity of best folding of a 2D set (or how to optimize a sandwich)

Tags: optimization, linear-algebra, computational-geometry

**Motivation:**
I was making lunch for my son, part of which is making a sandwich from two halves of a slice of bread. In order to minimize the parts of bread that have cheese on them, and are not covered by both halves, I need to find the optimal place to cut the bread.

I was wondering what the complexity of that is.

**Formal problem:**
Let $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ be either a polytope, or more generally a semialgebraic set.
For a line $\ell\in \mathbb{R}^2$, given by its normal $w\in \mathbb{R}^2$, we define the *cut* of $S$ by $\ell$ to be the two sets:
$$S_1=\{x\in S\ :\ x^Tw\ge  0\}\qquad S_2=\{x\in S\ :\ x^Tw<  0\}$$
Now, given an affine linear isometry $f(x)=Ax+b$, we can consider the area of $\Delta(S_1,f(S_2))$. That is, the area of the symmetric difference between $S_1$ and the isometry applied to $S_2$.

The problem is now the following:

> Given $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$, find a line $\ell$ and an affine isometry $f$ such that  $\Delta(S_1,f(S_2))$ is minimal.

If it helps, we can assume $S$ is convex (although homemade bread often isn't).

Comment: That is related to the maximizing the overlap. The translation version is quite easy, but the rotation very is nastier, and I dont remember what is known. A fast approximation might be an interesting problem. The introduction here mentioned some results  https://sarielhp.org/p/13/max_overlap/max_overlap.pdf
See also for a related problem: http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/danhalperin/publications/robotics/journal.pdf